# Ruby on Rails: Create an Array of Sums from Array of Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, sum

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[#<Holding id: 5, user_id: 21, outcome_id: 7, quantity: 200, cost_basis: nil, created_at: "2011-12-15 20:52:05", updated_at: "2011-12-15 20:52:05">,
 #<Holding id: 6, user_id: 21, outcome_id: 7, quantity: 750, cost_basis: nil, created_at: "2011-12-15 21:31:30", updated_at: "2011-12-15 21:31:30">,
 #<Holding id: 7, user_id: 21, outcome_id: 9, quantity: 1231, cost_basis: nil, created_at: "2011-12-15 21:35:31", updated_at: "2011-12-15 21:35:31">]
```

I retrieved this by using my model's find_all_by_user_id (Holding.find_all_by_user_id(21)). What I need, however, is an array of sums. So, for instance, what I'd like to get instead in this instance is:

```
[#<Holding id: 5, user_id: 21, outcome_id: 7, quantity: 950, cost_basis: nil, created_at: "2011-12-15 20:52:05", updated_at: "2011-12-15 20:52:05">,
     #<Holding id: 7, user_id: 21, outcome_id: 9, quantity: 1231, cost_basis: nil, created_at: "2011-12-15 21:35:31", updated_at: "2011-12-15 21:35:31">]
```

What would make it even better is if I could pull from my Outcomes model the Outcome.description and have it in this second array along with the id. Do I just have to loop over and create sums where outcome_id's match or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would do this in SQL - `SUM(quantity)` and `GROUP BY outcome_id`.

If you want it in Ruby, you can do

```
holdings = Holding.find_all_by_user_id(21)

sums = Hash.new(0)

holdings.each do |h|
  sums[h.outcome_id] += h.quantity
end
```

`sums` is now a hash with key being all the outcome_ids and the value being the total quantity.

Please note that in both solutions (SQL and Ruby) you will lose the information in the other fields (holding_id, user_id, cost_basis, timestamps), which may not be what you want.

Comment: I agree doing it in SQL is the better solution. It returns a lot less data which is always helpful, plus the DBM is made for that sort of lifting. The only time I'd retrieve the entire row is if I have to do subsequent processing of the data based on the sums.